# Autocomplete polygons while drawing with drawingManager using the Google Maps API v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, polygon

I have a basic Google Map, with a drawingManager, like this:

```
var mapOptions = {
    center: centroid,
    zoom: 14,
    scrollwheel: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
        mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID, google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP]
    }
}

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
    drawingControl: false,

    polygonOptions: {
        clickable: true,
        draggable: true,
        editable: true,
        fillColor: '#ffff00',
        fillOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 5
    }
});

drawingManager.setMap(map);
```

Drawing polygons on the map works like a charm, except for one little thing. I have to explicitly close my polygon, either by clicking the first point, or by double clicking somewhere (or at least, I can't find another way). But I would like for my polygon to be closed at all times while drawing, a bit like this:

http://www.birdtheme.org/useful/v3tool.html

(select 'polygon' in the first select box next to the title).

Now I know this example doesn't use the drawingManager, but creates the polygon by hand, but I am wondering if something similar is possible using the drawingManager. I'm afraid there isn't, since I can't seem to find any reference to it in the manual, but that also kind of surprised about that, since I would think it is something that more people would like to have.

Comment: I don't know about the drawingManager but using a standard polygon you could do something like `yourPolygon.getPath().push(getPath().getAt(0));` This would automatically close the polygon with the first point.

Comment: @MrUpsidown while that is true, the problem is that, when using the drawingManager, you have no access to the polygon until you explicitly complete that polygon.

Answer (score 0):

You could just make it yourself; you can easily register the click events.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', addLatLng);

poly = new google.maps.POLYGON(polyOptions);
poly.setMap(map);

function addLatLng(event) {

path = poly.getPath();
path.push(event.latLng);

}
```

Because you know the latlng of every point in you're polygon; you can just draw it.
You'll have to redraw it every time a new point is added.